# Is jQuery delayed executed just like LINQ?

Tags: jquery, linq

I am wondering in case I set a variable to a JQuery query, is it immediately executed, or delayed for when the control flow first try to access its result elements (say iterates on it)

With other words: Is a variable stores the query itself or instead it stores the result?

For example:

```
var $query = $('myselector'); // Is it traverses the DOM this time or later when actually using this variable?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is executed immediately, and the result is stored in the jQuery object. The jQuery object is an array-like object that contains references to the elements that were found.

If you later on add another element that would have been included by the selector, the result in the jQuery object won't change. It will still only contain the elements found when the query was executed.

As a contrast, some DOM methods like [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a live `NodeList` collection, that will change if you add or remove elements that match the name.

Comment: Thx. Is it comes from the specification, so it will not change, or just comes by examining the source, and in future implementations it may change depending on the implementor's intent?

Comment: @g.pickardou: I can't find it specified right now, but how this works is a fundamental part of how jQuery works, so it won't change in the future. The jQuery object is an array-like object that contains the result from the query.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not LINQ. When you call `$('myselector')` this is translated to a call to `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a list of nodes. There is no delayed loading. The list is also not "live." It represents the DOM at that time. So if you change it (add nodes, remove nodes), your list is not modified. It represents the state of the DOM at the time the selector was called. Mozilla has a great explanation of it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Also to note, in addition to calling `document.querySelectorAll`, sometimes, jQuery has to process the selector by itself using the Sizzle engine. This occurs when you use certain extensions that are not part of what `querySelectorAll` supports, or if you're using a browser that does not have this function. One such example is the `:eq(N)` pseudo-class. This is not part of `querySelectorAll` and so jQuery does all the heavy lifting. Note though, even if it is all done by Sizzle, it is still executed immediately and returns a non-live list of nodes matching the selector.

Comment: Note: In browsers where `querySelectorAll` is not supported, or if the query contains jQuery specific selectors, the Sizzle query engine will be used instead.